# How to see/display/debug the selected dom nodes with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any good way to see/debug the result of a jQuery selector ?

Let's say we have something like this

```
var arr = $('div > span').parent();
```

How can I see what the selector contains?

### Update

Just to make this a bit harder: Can I do the same in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: if you have firebug or using chrome/safari you can use the javascript console. then do console.log( $('div > span').parent() );

Comment: what do u want to do in jsfiddle? console is only avail in firebig or chrome

Comment: See some kind of output for the selectors

Comment: @Neal: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/2hbh2/

Comment: @Shaz , how do u include that with jquery? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = $('div > span').parent();
document.write(arr.html());
```

Comment: Why would you use document.write? That's not even proper code etiquette. document.write is "evil"

Answer (score 3):

in firebug or chrome console do:

```
console.log($('div > span').parent());
```

Comment: Just shows [object Object] in Firebug 2.0.4 and jQuery 1.10. Not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('div > span').parent())
```

with firebug or chrome.

Comment: Just shows [object Object] in Firebug 2.0.4 and jQuery 1.10. Not very useful.